# Adding a tag to an EC2 Snapshot using ec2-api-tools

Tags: amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

I've created a snapshot using `ec2-api-tools` of a volume within my AWS EC2 account. Currently I have:

```
>> ec2addsnap vol-xxxxxxxx -d 'My-first-Snapshot'
SNAPSHOT snap-12345678 vol-xxxxxxxx pending 2013-01-30T17:09:35+0000 086018780037 8 My-first-Snapshot
```

What I want to do is add a `--tag Name='Name Tag'` to this newly created snapshot from the `snap-12345678` id in the response.

This works>

```
>> ec2addtag snap-12345678 --tag Name='Name Tag'
```

How can I automate this? I've started writing a simple shell script - but I'm not sure how I would query the response from the initial `ec2addsnap` to grab the newly created snapshot id in order to apply `ec2addtag`?  Cheers (Thought I was posting this in Serverfault - my apologies)

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve this via the use of `awk`.  My Bash Script =

```
today=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")
tagname=$2
ec2addsnap vol-$1 -d $2'-'$today; 
ec2dsnap | grep $2'-'$today | awk -v tagname=$tagname '{print "Adding Tag too: " $2}; system("ec2addtag "$2" --tag Name=\""tagname"\"")';
```